# Linq Anonymous Type

Tags: c#, linq

I don't often use LINQ and the thing about it is that there are efficient ways of using it an less efficient ways.

I have a list of items, and I simply want to do a calculation on each and return the lowest calculated decimal number (note number, not item). I have this LINQ which works but I wonder if it is the most efficient way LINQ can be used in this scenario.

```
var bestPrice = query.Select(x => new
{
    Interest = CalcInterest(amount, term, x.ProductRate.Rate)
})
.OrderBy(x => x.Interest)
.FirstOrDefault();
```

Where "query" is a preselected LINQ list, and "CalcInterest" is a method used to calculate the number.

This query will be used a lot, so any small gains will be big wins.

Comment: Post this in code review mate :)

Comment: If you are interested in a more efficient way you need to provide `query` too. What is the type of the desired result at all? What is `Interest`? Why do you need the anonymous type if it only contains one decimal number?

Comment: @TimSchmelter - The content of the query is irrelevant, it's just a list of items that contains a Product Rate field. It sounds like I don't need an anonymous type -I refer back to my opening sentence and lack of LINQ experience.

Comment: Out of interest, what made you consider an anonymous type for this query?

Comment: @Gusdor - lack of experience :)

Comment: @JohnOhara We all start somewhere! Was there a particular article you read or some wording that made it seem like a key part of Linq that you had to understand and use? I'm asking because I am responsible for delivering C# training and I know Linq is a big shift from the rest of c#.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need anonymous types here, I think. Try this:

```
var bestPrice = query.Min(x => CalcInterest(amount, term, x.ProductRate.Rate));
```

Edit: playing around with it I realized this created a different result. Your code returns an anon type. This just returns the object which has the lowest interest. The interest data isn't preserved.

Either way, use `Min` to get the minimum.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - it seems to be exactly what I need.